# Angular 8 - With "ng-translate" it does not translate a specific property

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am using the "ngx-translate" library to implement internationalization in my App.

This is my translation file: "en.txt":

```
{
    "error-msg":{
        "email-required":"Email is required",
        "msgEmailWrongFormatted":"Please enter a valid email address",
        "error-no-student-or-alumni":"Must be a pupil or student" 
    }
}
```

This is the html file where I am doing the translation:

```
<div id="errorLogin" class="errorLogin">
<span translate>error-msg.error-no-student-or-alumni</span>
</div>
```

The problem I have is that the property "error-no-student-or-alumni" does not translate it correctly.

Example 1: (This works ok):

```
<div id="errorLogin" class="errorLogin">
<span translate>error-msg.msgEmailWrongFormatted</span>
</div>
```

This shows me in the screen:

```
Please enter a valid email address
```

Example 2: (This works ok: even adding a new property):

```
<div id="errorLogin" class="errorLogin">
<span translate>error-msg.email-required</span>
</div>
```

Example 3: (But this property is failing me):

```
<div id="errorLogin" class="errorLogin">
<span translate>error-msg.error-no-student-or-alumni</span>
</div>
```

When it fails me, the translation does not apply and the screen I shows me directly:

```
error-msg.error-no-student-or-alumni
```

I have renamed the property "error-no-student-or-alumni" and it doesn't work for me.

What could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: seems strange. The only 3 reasons I would think of: 1) mispelling of the translation key. 2) the last HTML is not on the same component, and this component's module doesn't import `translatModule.forChild()`. 3) space-time anomaly, restart your `npm start`.

Comment: oh, maybe a fourth: There is an error somewhere else in the console, stopping javascript thread before it gets the translation...

Comment: What a mistake, in the configuration of the translation file in the "app.module" it pointed to a URL that did not have that property, thanks for the advice

Comment: return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, "./assets/i18n/", ".txt"); (Before it pointed to another URL that did not have that property)